# Convert stl 2 numpy, volume data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to convert a **stl file to a numpy** array?
The numpy array, resolved with `x*y*z` datapoints should contain volumetric information in the sense of "inside" or "outside" the geometry, say as 0 or 1.

To my surprise I didn't find anything on this yet, although numpy2stl seems to be quite popular.

The problem is a complex geometry of porous media, so convex hull conversion does not work either.

```
import numpy
import stl
from stl import mesh
stl.stl.MAX_COUNT = 1e10
your_mesh = stl.mesh.Mesh.from_file('Data.stl')
print your_mesh.data
```

seems to be able to export triangles only.

In addition, even this usually leads to `MemoryError` messages; but numpy-stl (usually) works for loading the datapoints into numpy.

Is there a way to convert the stl data into volume data that contains information if every point is inside or outside the geometry?
The resulting 3D array could technically be of binary data type, but this isn't required.
overcomplicated
With commercial software this conversion seems to be trivial, but it's not python or free. Implementing a ray casting algorithm from scratch seems over complicated for file type conversion.

Comment: Have you tried numpy-stl? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-stl

Comment: @rennomarcus As far as I understand this is loading the stl file with numpy-stl. How would numpy-stl be able to give me volume information?

Comment: I've never used this library and I don't have STL files to test either... Is this what you want? https://w.wol.ph/2015/01/28/readingwriting-3d-stl-files-numpy-stl/
There are many examples at https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl

Comment: Is the question how to load the STL data, or is the qeustion how to determine "inside" and "outside" for arbitrary volumes?

Comment: @ChristophTerasa I tried to improve the question, loading the data from file works reasonably well, determining "inside" and "outside" is the big problem.

Comment: There are languages that describe solids in the way we experience them, not as collection of surfaces. Think about a solid as a boolean union, subtraction, intersection etc. of geometric 3d primitives. Such languages would be suitable to get actual volumetric info. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry    If you could find a good converter between STL and one of those languages, volume calculations should become doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do believe that what you want to do is a voxelization of your volume. You can do that with the `trimesh` package at https://trimsh.org/

```py
import trimesh
mesh = trimesh.load_mesh('path2yourstlfile.stl')
assert(mesh.is_watertight) # you cannot build a solid if your volume is not tight
volume = mesh.voxelized(pitch=0.1)
mat = volume.matrix # matrix of boolean
```

You can also check if a list of point are inside the volume using:

```
mesh.contains(points)
```

Comment: @jack95 thanks for the fix

Answer (score 1):

Small typo in [4], trimesh has no matrix atribute, you get it from VoxelGrid.

```
mat = mesh.matrix
```

fixed

```
mat = volume.matrix
```